# What does a vei character (downward caret) mean in a recorded Xcode UITest session?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitest

I have recorded clicking on a button in a tab bar using Xcode 9.1's UITest record button. The recorded interaction in Test.swift appears below:
[image]

It's unclear to me what the downward caret means or does. Can someone provide a nice explanation? Apple's UITest documentation did not help me.

Comment: I believe it's a "vel" character:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vel_(symbol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caret means that Xcode knows there are other ways to access that user interface element. Click the caret for a menu of all the ways Xcode knows how to access it:

[image: access path menu]

Brooke Callahan demonstrates this in [WWDC 2015 Session 406 “UI Testing in Xcode”](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/?time=2048) starting around 34:10. He refers to the carets as “tokens”.

Comment: When I 'select' one of the choices, the selected item does not compile. Why might that be?

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to show what the code looks like after the selection.